# Horus fresh install: Account Disabled

Tags: system-installation, greeter

I've installed Horus, and on two occasions it has brought me to a new login screen with the account disabled.   So now I can't even log in to run etcher and make a different disk image of something that might work.

I do know that the install process automatically does LVM now, which is simply too complicated for me to want to spend time on.

Why is this chosen automatically now?

Comment: seems like you are not the only one: <br/>  https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/10wj7vb/account_dissabled/    and   https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/10zwqob/account_is_disabled_wont_let_me_login_right_after/

Comment: Still no dice?  Arggh!!  I would very much like to just get this installed and run it as my daily driver, as I do believe in this project for many reasons, but I simply can't use it if I can't rely on it.